# References - Include SQLCLRTYPES as a reference

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlclr, software-distribution

I'm using `SqlClrTypes` and everything is ok until I give my app to another PC. It crashes and it only works after i install `SqlClrTypes` on that PC. Can i somehow include it to my project?

Comment: My assumption is that you use `SqlClrTypes` outside of SQL Server? If so, what is your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to include the installer for SqlClrTypes in your distribution. You can get it — **SQLSysClrTypes.msi** — from the following location:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676

There are many individual MSI files there, but you only need to get the one or two files with the name "SQLSysClrTypes.msi" (one or two depending on if you need 32-bit and/or 64-bit version).

This is redistributable, at least according to the 2016 version. Here is where I found the license file on my system:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Licenses\1033\SysClrTypes_SQLServer_Sql2016.rtf**

I doubt they would be changing it for SQL Server 2017 or newer given that anyone using this would need to distribute the installer for any desktop software they are developing.